# How to inspect Cassandra table's internal structure without cassandra-cli?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-cli

As for Cassandra 3.0, the utility named "cassandra-cli" was removed. It allowed to see how the table is stored internally. Like here:

```
RowKey: title1
=> (name=, value=, timestamp=1393102991499000)
=> (name=author, value=Some Author, timestamp=1393102991499000)
=> (name=year, value=1993, timestamp=1393102991499000)
RowKey: title2
=> (name=, value=, timestamp=1393102991499100)
=> (name=author, value=Another Author, timestamp=1393102991499100)
=> (name=year, value=1987, timestamp=1393102991499100)
```

How to do that in Cassandra >= 3.0?

Comment: What info do you have there that you don't have with `cqlsh`?

Comment: @CedricH. I need to get the data that I have included in the question. How can I do that with cqlsh? I need the representation of the data. I don't want to see it in the tabular representation, I would like to see how data is split by partitions, to see how clustering columns are prefixed, etc.

Comment: You know that once you know the CQL schema, you don't even need to query data... The representation is well known and is the same as before.

Comment: @CedricH. I need to see if I have wide or narrow partitions, it's much easier to look into that kind of information seeing the data in the format of how Cassandra stores it - in SSTable format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Cassandra 3.0 they changed the sstable format and didn't update the tools for debugging the contents, so those tools were removed. See [CASSANDRA-7464](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7464).

If you read the comments, it looks like some people are working on an updated version of sstable2json for 3.x.

Comment: This is the new tool: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/ToolsSSTabledump.html you can find it in apache-cassandra\tools\bin